# Check payment in Paypal Sandbox account iOS

Tags: ios, paypal

I am working on PayPal Payment Gateway. When I do payment from my personal account the payment is not showing up in merchant account. Can anyone tell me how to check ?

Answer (score 2):

If your are working with sandbox mode then you can login with sandbox user. 
Create sandbox user account and use it. You can create multiple accounts for testing.
If you are working on live mode then you can login with Paypal account.

Comment: But how to verify whether I am getting amount in my PayPal Merchant account or not. I simply pass Client_Id of his production type in the app.

Comment: Can anyone will tell me how to check it ?

Comment: First you have to check it with sandbox accounts.

Comment: If sandbox working then try with live account and transfer small amount like 0.5$ or 1.0$.